# Hide or Manipulate URL in browser left-bottom side when mouse curser placed in ahref tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I want to hide, remove or manipulate URL display in left-bottom in browser like Google.

**Trying with JS:**

```
<a href="https://example.com" onmouseover="window.status='google.com'; return true;" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true;">Example</a>
```

**Trying with CSS :**

```css
.no-tooltip:hover::after {
  content: none !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com" class="no-tooltip">Link</a>
```

**Google example :**

[image]

In Google, when you place pointer in any search result or ahref tag it show URL Status like above screenshot but when you click it or copy it you will find different `https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwizyLqk54X-AhWIUGwGHeqDA5EQFnoECCUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw2g9Si57HiLP2X7LeNGKaHd`

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status: _"Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it"_, _"The status property of the Window interface was originally intended to set the text in the status bar at the bottom of the browser window. However, the HTML standard now requires setting window.status to have no effect on the text displayed in the status bar."_

Comment: This has explicitly been deprecated, because too many shady developers used it for shady purposes, i.e. disguising where a link will actually take the user. So why do _you_ think you need this, what would be your non-shady use case here?

Comment: _"Trying with CSS:"_ - that made no sense to begin with, the status bar is _not_ a pseudo element of the link ...

Comment: @CBroe to hide my affiliate link. anyway, that i do not accurately change or remove the status instead i call url using something called javascript void (0) or similar?

Comment: _"to hide my affiliate link"_ - why? Why can't you be _honest_ about the fact that you are using them, and instead feel the need to _cheat_ me?

Comment: Of course you can remove the href attribute or make it `#`, and then use a click handler to get the user to the URL by assigning it to `location.href` ... but again, bad move IMHO. Would leave me with nothing but the impression that this is a shady site that should be avoided in the future. (Plus, you might even "lose business", when a user tries to open such a link in a background tab via right click then, which will not work.)

Comment: @CBroe hidding not from users. hidding from affiliate network. and cheating is something doing wrong. i am just hidding url not cheating user.

Comment: @CBroe you say not possible but `Google` doing this. for example, if you place pointer in any search result it will show `example.com` but when you click, copy, etc the real url will be like `google.com/url?blablabla` - **Updated my question**

Comment: _"hidding not from users. hidding from affiliate network."_ - why (and _how_) would your affiliate network look at _my_ browser status bar? And why do you need to "hide" it from _them_ in the first place?

Comment: _"you say not possible but Google doing this"_ - no, they are doing something else. They have the href of the link actually point to `https://example.com/` in this case - and then use JavaScript to manipulate that URL, the moment the user clicks that link. I did not say _that_ was impossible, but in fact that is pretty close to the alternative I already suggested to you.

Comment: @CBroe Affiliate networks always try to get there affiliate information and run the campaign by there own team to make more revenue and this is not something hidden. For, this there is many tool like masking URL (url1 redirects to url2), landing page protection, etc etc. i am just using direct link without masking, so i am looking for solution some how i can hide my affiliate url. because masking URL will make me have 1 more redirects which decrease user experience

Comment: @CBroe `then use JavaScript to manipulate that URL` - help me how to do this. any sample js code

Comment: _"Affiliate networks always try to get there affiliate information and run the campaign by there own team to make more revenue"_ - and you think hiding the actual link target in the status bar would prevent that? When they could simply _click_ your link once, and then will found out where it _actually_ goes anyway ...?

Comment: _"elp me how to do this. any sample js code"_ - keyword `location.href` has already been mentioned. If it doesn't mean anything to you yet, then please do your own research first of all. Or manipulate the actual `href` attribute content with a _click_ handler.

Comment: "you think hiding the actual link target in the status bar would prevent that?" - No, it wont protect but make difficult. Even you put 10K USD lock on your house door, thief can still steal. Even you got 8+ airbag in car, you can still die from accident. All we do here is to make it more harder to get it break or damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change `Window.status`. To achive desire result, you can use `location.href` or `location.replace`

```js
  var link = document.getElementById("my-link");
  link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
    
    // Change the href to the new URL
    link.href = "https://www.example.com";
    
    // Redirect to the new URL
    //window.location.href = link.href;
    window.location.replace(link.href);
  });
```

```html
<a id="my-link" href="https://www.google.com" data-mc-cta="1" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

**To include left-clicks, right-clicks and contextmenu**

```js
var link = document.getElementById("my-link");

function redirectLink(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
  link.href = "https://www.example.com"; // Change the href to the new URL
  window.location.replace(link.href); // Redirect to the new URL
}

// Listen for left-click and contextmenu events
link.addEventListener("click", redirectLink);
link.addEventListener("contextmenu", redirectLink);
```

```html
<a id="my-link" href="https://www.google.com" data-mc-cta="1" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

**For multiple URL using class & for-loop**

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");

function redirectLink(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
  this.href = "https://example.com"; // Change the href to the new URL
  window.location.replace(this.href); // Redirect to the new URL
}

// Loop through all links with the afflink class and add event listeners
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", redirectLink);
  links[i].addEventListener("contextmenu", redirectLink);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="link"> Google </a>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" class="link"> Yahoo </a>
<a href="https://www.bing.com" class="link"> Bing </a>
```

**Only Right click to all `a href` with respective URL**

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   links[i].addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     window.location.replace(this.href);
   });
 }
```

```html
<a href="https://www.Example.com"> Example </a>
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.com"> Wikipedia </a>
<a href="https://www.bing.com"> Bing </a>
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"> stackoverflow </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.preventDefault` to block link propagation and then redirect to another page with javascript.

Here's a simple example:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
   $("a").click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault(); //stop the redirect
       location.href="https://www.wikipedia.org"; 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="link">
    <a href="http://www.google.it">Google</a>
</div>
```

Hope i was helpful!